# What is the space size of a Colossal Animated Ship?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters, battle-map, creature-size

In *Pathfinder* I am currently trying to design a few encounters with a supposed ghost ship (actually a [Colossal Animated Object](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/constructs/animated-object)) complete with a crew of Haunted Objects (again, Animated Objects), but I am having a few difficulties with the logistics behind my concept that I cannot ignore.

One of the biggest concerns I have is with the ship's Size vs. its occupied Spaces. While looking over the [Space, Reach & Threatened Area Templates](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/space-reach-threatened-area-templates), I found that a Colossal creature is either 64 feet tall or long, which would be a perfect length for a small ship that the party could board and fight with the crew. However, in the same row, it says that they also cover a space of 30ftX30ft. Since the creature in question is a ship, and a large raft with a 65ft sail is dumb, **could I fit the ship in a 60ftX30ft area that the party can climb/board on top of?** If not, **could I slide around a 30ftx30ft square for the hull of the ship, and have a separate map that represents the deck/quarters of the ship?**

Comment: If you're keeping this in the rules, I don't the party can legally stand on top of the ship. You might be going into houserule terroritory already.

Comment: @Erik uuuuuuugh

Comment: @Erik Houserules of such sort are good things to design. "It is not described in the rules properly" is a bad reason to give up good story idea and (most likely) interesting encounter model!

Comment: I feel "give me houserules for this" is a very different question from how it's worded now.

Comment: @Erik Question also lacks RAW tag. So it might be solwed by wise houserulling if needed.

Comment: Given that you've "exported" offensive mechanics into separate entities (cannon golems), is there still a reason to treat the ship as a 'monster' rather than a piece of moving scenery that is controlled by AI NPC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The values on the table [Space, Reach, & Threatened Area Templates](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/space-reach-threatened-area-templates) are just *guidelines*, most creatures will follow those rules but not all of them have to.

One example of a creature that completely ignores the table can be found on **AP#27: Council of Thieves - What Lies in Dust**, which has the [Aspidochelone](http://www.archivesofnethys.com/MonsterDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Aspidochelone), a CR 17 N Colossal creature with a listed Space of **150 ft.**.

While [the Great Old One, Cthulhu](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/aberrations/great-old-ones/great-old-one-cthulhu), has a listed size of **40 ft.** and reach of also **40 ft.**.

If you allow me to give you a suggestion, you can use the **Boarding Action** (or another similar map) flip mat to represent the creature's actual size.

[image: Boarding Action]

Answer (score 0):

It's your creation. So while you might not like this answer you are totally within your rights as DM to give custom monsters custom features. (Assuming you aren't running according to the rules of Adventurers League.) The players are unlikely to make a big deal out of it — what they might make a big deal out of is *not* being able to board it.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]! As many, *many* of the site's questions can be answered with [*Just make up your own stuff*](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5940/8610), telling the asker that he can safely make up such things isn't usually helpful. If this answer can include your experiences with having created your own Colossal animated ships for your campaigns, that'd be great. Thank you for participating and have fun.